# Overriding assign method

Tags: php, oop, templates, overriding, smarty

I'm trying to override the assign method of smarty object and then call the parent one.

```
class View extends Smarty
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

    public function assign($name, $value)
    {
     // some code that manipulate the values of $name and $value
     // .......

     parent::assign($name, $value, false);
    }

}

$tpl = new View();
$tpl->assign('name', 'index.tpl');
```

At this point I get

```
Strict standards: Declaration of View::assign() should be compatible with Smarty_Internal_Data::assign($tpl_var, $value = NULL, $nocache = false) in /Users/me/Projects/smarty/View.php on line 6
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used the same method name, you are overriding parent method. In that case you need to follow Smarty's `assign()` parameters in your own (as if using interface).

Try this:

```
public function assign($name, $value = null, $nocache = false)
{
 // some code that manipulate the values of $name and $value
 // .......

 parent::assign($name, $value, $nocache);
}
```

### Side note:

When you initialize object of child class, you don't need to call parent's constructor. So you can get rid of this code as it's completely useless as it is:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Smartie base class already has a multiple parameter "assign" function with default values. You don't need your two parameter assign function as it then is classed as "shadowing" without properly overriding. If you need to override, you should make the signatures the same.

```
public function assign($tpl_var, $value = NULL, $nocache = false)
```

otherwise, you call (polymorphic/inheritance stylee),

```
myobj.assign("bob", "myvalue")
```

it doesn't know which one to call as you've shadowed the same function with a default parameter.

Given your function is a straight passthrough with the default value, unless you've clipped some business logic, the function is pretty much redundant.